# Working with folders other than inbox in Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Using Excel VBA I can retrieve the email body and subject from Inbox.

```
Set ObjO = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olNs = ObjO.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objFolder = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(6)

For Each item1 In objFolder.Items

    Dim sa, bc
    bc = item1.ReceivedTime
    sa = Format(item1.ReceivedTime, "dd-MM-yyyy")

    If item1.UnRead And item1.SenderEmailAddress = "harshahowrang@gmail.com" And sa = spa Then
```

Here Defaultfolder(6) is for Inbox.

All mails come into CRM folder so I need to change the folder path.

I tried other numbers which are not working and don't point to CRM folder in Outlook mailbox.

How do I point to CRM folder?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Simply use*

```
Set objfolder = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) _
                    .Parent.Folders("CRM")
```

Full Example

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Example()
    Dim ObjO As Object
    Set ObjO = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim olNs As Object
    Set olNs = ObjO.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Dim objfolder As Object
    Set objfolder = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) _
                        .Parent.Folders("CRM")

    objfolder.Display

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the folder like this:

`Set objFolder = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("CRM")`

Else check the named folders in `Inbox` for it:

```
Set objFolder = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(6)
For Each oFolder In objFolder.Folders
    Debug.Print oFolder.Name
Next
```

**Edit:** After seeing the image you posted,

To access folders on the same level as `Inbox` you can do:

`Set objFolder = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(6).Parent.Folders("CRM")`

Or iterate through `.Parent.Folders` to get the CRM Folder name.